# How to write commands into the Firefox console using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, console

I open Firefox console, using Selenium Webdriver.

```
@Test
public void seleniumFirefoxConsole() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\FirefoxDriver\\geckodriver.exe");

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.addArguments("-console");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  }
```

How can I write commands in this console using Java code like this:

```
console.log("Hello, Firefox console from selenium");
```

[Firefox opened console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvypJ.jpg)

Comment: Why do you wanna write in FF console ?

Answer (score 0):

use the [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) do run javascript commands from selenium.
Simply add the following lines to your test case:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("console.log('Hello, Firefox console from selenium');");
```

by the way - whats your use case?